# Отключить питание определенного USB порта через cmd

Tags: cmd, usb

Требуется отключить питание одного из USB портов на ноутбуке через командную строку cmd.

```
reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\UsbStor /v "Start" /t REG_DWORD /d "4 или 3" /f
```

Пробовал это, но команда отключает только доступ usb накопителей, а не питание порта.

Comment: А разве такое возможно сделать?

Comment: ИМХО, не каждый USB-хаб поддерживает отключения питания конкретного порта. И со времён Vista MS "отключила отключение" при отсоединении USB-устройств.  Не знаю, удастся ли решить вопрос с помощью ключа DisableOnSoftRemove в реестре....